# how tf.space_to_depth() works in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, pytorch

I am a pytorch user. I have got a pretrained model in tensorflow and I would like to transfer it into pytorch. In one part of model architecture, I mean in tensorflow-defined model, there is a function **tf.space_to_depth** which transfers an input size of (None, 38,38,64) to (None, 19,19, 256). (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/space_to_depth) is the doc of this function. But I could not understand what this function actually do. Could you please provide some numpy codes to illustrate it for me?

Actually I would like to make an exact similar layer in pytorch.

Some codes in tensorflow reveals another secret:
Here is some codes:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

norm = tf.random_normal([1, 2, 2, 1], mean=0, stddev=1)
trans = tf.space_to_depth(norm,2)

with tf.Session() as s:
    norm = s.run(norm)
    trans = s.run(trans)



print("Norm")
print(norm.shape)
for index,value in np.ndenumerate(norm):
    print(value)

print("Trans")
print(trans.shape)
for index,value in np.ndenumerate(trans):
    print(value)
```

And here is the output:

```
Norm
(1, 2, 2, 1)
0.695261
0.455764
1.04699
-0.237587
Trans
(1, 1, 1, 4)
1.01139
0.898777
0.210135
2.36742
```

As you can see above, In Addition to data reshaping, the tensor values has changed!

Comment: Your values are probably changing because you have to separate session.run calls for norm and trans so the generated random values are different between calls.

Comment: That is, try Try `norm, trans = s.run([norm, trans])` instead.

Answer (score 4):

This tf.space_to_depth divides your input into blocs and concatenates them.

In your example the input is 38x38x64 (and I guess the block_size is 2). So the function divides your input into 4 (block_size x block_size) and concatenates them which gives your 19x19x256 output.

You just need to divide each of your channel (input) into block_size*block_size patches (each patch has a size of width/block_size x height/block_size) and concatenate all of these patches. Should be pretty straightforward with numpy.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I think some data shuffling has done! Did you see it in its docs! I think it is more than division!

Comment: I didn't see any shuffling in tensorflow doc (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/space_to_depth) .. but maybe there is :)

Comment: Hi again. thanks for your response. Could you please provide some numpy code to do this division. I am really novice in tensorflow and numpy. I would like to have the exact result as tf.space_to_depth. please!

Answer (score 4):

**Conclusion**:  `tf.space_to_depth()` only outputs a copy of the input tensor where values from the height and width dimensions are moved to the depth dimension.

If you modify your code a little bit, like this

```
norm = tf.random_normal([1, 2, 2, 1], mean=0, stddev=1)

with tf.Session() as s:
    norm = s.run(norm)

trans = tf.space_to_depth(norm,2)

with tf.Session() as s:
    trans = s.run(trans)
```

Then you will have the following results:

```
Norm
(1, 2, 2, 1)
-0.130227
2.04587
-0.077691
-0.112031
Trans
(1, 1, 1, 4)
-0.130227
2.04587
-0.077691
-0.112031
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: great conclusion. Maybe adding some information about data shuffling in this operation is nice!

Answer (score 2):

A good reference for PyTorch is the implementation of the PixelShuffle module [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/functional.py#L563). This shows the implementation of something equivalent to Tensorflow's [depth_to_space](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/depth_to_space). Based on that we can implement pixel_shuffle with a scaling factor less than 1 which would be like space_to_depth. E.g., downscale_factor=0.5 is like space_to_depth with block_size=2.

```
def pixel_shuffle_down(input, downscale_factor):
    batch_size, channels, in_height, in_width = input.size()
    out_channels = channels / (downscale_factor ** 2)
    block_size = 1 / downscale_factor

    out_height = in_height * downscale_factor
    out_width = in_width * downscale_factor

    input_view = input.contiguous().view(
        batch_size, channels, out_height, block_size, out_width, block_size)

    shuffle_out = input_view.permute(0, 1, 3, 5, 2, 4).contiguous()
    return shuffle_out.view(batch_size, out_channels, out_height, out_width)
```

Note: I haven't verified this implementation yet and I'm not sure if it's exactly the inverse of pixel_shuffle but this is the basic idea. I've also opened an issue on the PyTorch Github about this [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/1684). In NumPy the equivalent code would use `reshape`and `transpose` instead of `view` and `permute` respectively.

Comment: Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 2):

Using split and stack functions along with permute in Pytorch gives us the same result as space_to_depth in tensorflow does. Here is the code in Pytorch.
Assume that input is in BHWC format.

Based on block_size and input shape, we can caculate the output shape.
First, it splits the input on the "width" dimension or dimension #2 by block_size. The result of this operation is an array of length d_width. It's just like you cut a cake (by block_size) into d_width pieces. 
Then for each piece, you reshape it so it has correct output height and output depth (channel). Finally, we stack those pieces together and perform a permutation.

Hope it helps.

```
def space_to_depth(input, block_size)
    block_size_sq = block_size*block_size
    (batch_size, s_height, s_width, s_depth) = input.size()
    d_depth = s_depth * self.block_size_sq
    d_width = int(s_width / self.block_size)
    d_height = int(s_height / self.block_size)
    t_1 = input.split(self.block_size, 2)
    stack = [t_t.contiguous().view(batch_size, d_height, d_depth) for t_t in t_1]
    output = torch.stack(stack, 1)
    output = output.permute(0, 2, 1, 3)
    return output
```

Comment: Can you explain why would someone need such an operation?

Answer (score -1):

maybe this one works:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

it worked for me.